# How to solve this integral? $\int_0^1(t^2+t^4+t^6)\sqrt{1+4t^2+9t^4}\,dt$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How can this integral be solved?
$$\int_0^1(t^2+t^4+t^6)\sqrt{1+4t^2+9t^4}\,dt$$
This integral came from a problem where the question was to solve the integral $\int_Cx^2+y^2+z^2\,ds$ where $C$ is the curve defined by $x=t$, $y=t^2$, and $z=t^3$ on the interval $t\in[0,1]$. I simplified it to the single variable integral that I wrote above.

Comment: Are you sure the question is to actually evaluate this integral, not just to set it up? Wolfram Mathematica can't evaluate it, which is a sign that it's a really tough one, probably doesn't have a closed form answer.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. I was told to evaluate it.

Comment: If it doesn't have a closed form you can always use Taylor polynomials to approximate it to arbitrary precision.

Comment: From the appearance of a quartic under square root it is clear that the integral is not elementary. It can be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals. A better approach would be to go for numerical evaluation of the integral.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh.There is a closed form expression (I am working it).

Comment: @industryfatcat. I do not think that Taylor expansion would be a way to go since the coefficients are larger and larger (not to say huge).

Comment: What a *horrendous* problem!

Answer (score 3):

Using a CAS, there is a nasty closed form of 
$$I=\int(t^2+t^4+t^6)\sqrt{1+4t^2+9t^4}\,dt$$ in which appear  the complete elliptic integral and  the elliptic integral of the first kind as we could expect because of the quartic inside the radical).

I shall not reproduce here the formula and limit to the value of the definite integral. $$J=\int_0^1(t^2+t^4+t^6)\sqrt{1+4t^2+9t^4}\,dt$$ After a lot of manual simplifications (they can be continued expanding the complex numbers), I arrived to 
$$2066715 \sqrt{\frac{7}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+2 i\right)}\,J=$$ $$-\sqrt[4]{-1} \left(7314237 (-1)^{3/4} \sqrt{\sqrt{5}+2 i}+\sqrt{14} \left(12964
   \left(\sqrt{5}+2 i\right) E\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{3+3 i}{\sqrt{2 \left(-2
   i+\sqrt{5}\right)}}\right)|\frac{2 i-\sqrt{5}}{2 i+\sqrt{5}}\right)-\left(12964
   \sqrt{5}+57635 i\right) F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{3+3 i}{\sqrt{2 \left(-2
   i+\sqrt{5}\right)}}\right)|\frac{2 i-\sqrt{5}}{2
   i+\sqrt{5}}\right)\right)\right)$$ which evaluates to $$J=1.8882169294873728762987425057609170751656006220719$$ which matches the numerical integration.

**Edit**

You could notice that 
$$\frac{3+3 i}{\sqrt{2 \left(\sqrt{5}-2 i\right)}}=-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right)+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right)+i
   \left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right)+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right)\right)$$
$$\frac{2i-\sqrt{5}}{2i+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{-1+4 i \sqrt{5}}{9}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{7}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+2 i\right)}=\sqrt{\frac{21}{2}} \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right)+i \sqrt{\frac{21}{2}} \sin
   \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right)$$

I think that the complexity of the result comes from the fact that the roots of $1+4t^2+9t^4=0$ are given by $$\frac 1 {\sqrt 3}\left(\pm\sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right)\pm i \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right) \right)$$

Comment: I don't particularly like the way certain CASs insist on using complex moduli/parameters when the elliptic integral itself is real. I'll see what I can do myself later... but if you want to beat me to it, formula 264.08 in [Byrd/Friedman](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-65138-0) ought to do it.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician. I totally agree with you. Unfortunately, I do not get access to the book.

Comment: Did you do all that $\mathrm\LaTeX $ typing by hand or does your CAS generates $\mathrm\LaTeX $?